# c++ linked list deallocation error: Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-management

In LinkedList.h I have the following code:

```
#ifndef LINK_H
#define LINK_H
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *link;
};
#endif
```

In my Main.cpp I have the following code:

```
    int size = 1;
int data = 0;

cout << "How big for linked list? ";
cin >> size;
cout << endl;

Node<int> *head;
Node<int> *node = new Node<int>[size];

head = &node[0];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << "Input data for link " << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> node[i].data;
    if (i < size - 1)
        node[i].link = &node[i + 1];
    else
        node[i].link = NULL;
}

Node<int> *ptr = head;
cout << "Linked list has current data: ";

while (ptr)
{
    cout << ptr->data << " ";
    ptr = ptr->link;
}

cout << endl << endl << "What data do you want to add to the front of the list? ";
cin >> data;
cout << endl;

//add
Node<int> *loc = new Node<int>;
loc->data = data;
loc->link = head;
head = loc;

cout << "Linked list has current data: ";

ptr = head;

while (ptr)
{
    cout << ptr->data << " ";
    ptr = ptr->link;
}

cout << endl << endl << "Deleting the data you just added." << endl;

//delete single
Node<int> *temp = new Node<int>;
temp = head;
head = head->link;
delete temp;

cout << "Linked list has current data: ";

ptr = head;

while (ptr)
{
    cout << ptr->data << " ";
    ptr = ptr->link;
}

cout << endl;

//delete entire list
ptr = head;

while (ptr)
{
    cout << "/";
    Node<int> *old = new Node<int>;
    old = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->link;
    delete old;
}

cout << endl;
```

Upon attempting to deallocate this linked list, I get an error like the one in the title and my program crashes. It seems like c++ is trying to access memory it no longer has access to, and it has something to do with my loc pointer / adding a new link to the front of the list. Can anyone tell me where my code went wrong? The parts that say code removed are basically just couts to print what's in the linked list.

Edit: The error occurs after 2 iterations through the last while loop.

Edit2: It seems after I call the line:

```
 delete temp;
```

head loses its link and returns garbage. Why?

Comment: Look like your tail might be pointing to garbage. Why not declare a constructor for Node and initialize link to nullptr

Comment: @parapurarajkumar, the error comes after 2 iterations through the last while loop, no matter the size of the list. The tail of the list points to NULL but I left that code out because it's not what's causing the error.

Comment: you didnt show the definition of head?

Comment: @paulm I have edited in the entire code now

Comment: You are double deleting your data, and mixing new[] with delete! Boom, your memory management is totally screwed.

Comment: @paulm could you specify where in my code I am mixing new with delete?

Comment: Node<int> *node = new Node<int>[size]; then head = &node[0]; then ptr = head; then delete old; after you've already delete temp; which was Node<int> *temp = head;

Comment: @paulm But I moved the location of head to the next node before deleting temp: Node<int> *temp = head; then: head = head->link; So all I did was move head to the next node, then delete the previous node to delete the first element in the linked list.

Comment: @paulm It seems after I call the line:

 delete temp;
head loses its link and returns garbage. Why?

Comment: Firstly, is it necessary to allocate memory to temp, can't you simply do Node<int> *temp = head; and then do delete[] instead of delete because you are specifying an array